react-pdf font doesn't change
I'm trying to make a PDF that uses the courier font, but the file doesn't change to it
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
      fontFamily: "Courier"
    }
  });

const MakePDF = () => {
    return (<Document><Page size="A4"><View>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>test</Text>
                </View></Page></Document>)}

export default ExportPDF

it keeps just using the default font. I've already tried importing directly from a file on the computer, but it still doesn't work

One of the simplest ways to check your React-PDF functions is via the repl.
https://react-pdf.org/repl
There is no such Font as Courier as it is an PDF Alias for  Monospaced fonts provided by the Platform Hardware (Windows has that as a FON file not a TTF).
Google fonts provide a substitute called CourierPrime and you can download that and use it rather than a CDN font.


Here is the working code but do use your own local ttf.
Font.register({
  family: 'CourierPrime',
  src: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/quoteunquoteapps/CourierPrime/master/fonts/ttf/CourierPrime-Regular.ttf',
 });

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    paddingTop: 35,
    paddingBottom: 65,
    paddingHorizontal: 35,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'CourierPrime',  
    color: 'red',
  },
  author: {
    fontSize: 12,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'CourierPrime',
    marginBottom: 40,
  },


React Native's built-in stylesheet does not directly control the font behavior in generated PDFs.
try installing the react-pdf package with
npm i @react-pdf/renderer

and import the stylesheet and Font:
import {Document, Page, StyleSheet, Font} from '@react-pdf/renderer';

make sure to download the font from google fonts https://fonts.google.com/
place this code before your Stylesheet to use Courier as font
import CourierRegular from './styles/pdfFonts/Courier.ttf';

 Font.register({
      family: 'Courier',
      fonts: [{ {src: CourierRegular}],
    });

Maintain the existing styles. By following these steps, you should be able to successfully use the Courier font in your React Native PDF generation using @react-pdf/renderer.
